# ValueError; low >= high

Tags: python, while-loop

I am getting "low >= high" error in the loop code below, how can it be resolved?

```
while True:
    max_num = 1000
    num_1 = np.random.randint(1, max_num)
    num_2 = np.random.randint(1, max_num)

    if (num_1 < num_2):
        num_2 = np.random.randint(1, num_1)
    break
```

Comment: When you get an error, look at the traceback, it will tell you which line of code the error occurred on. This is useful info to put in the question. Here it seems like the error would occur if `num_1` is equal to `1`... leading to `np.random.randint(1, 1)` i.e. low >= high, where 'low' and 'high' are the args to randint. If we look at the [docs for randint](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) we can see this case is possible because it returns _"random integers from low (inclusive) to high (exclusive)."_ i.e. `randint(1, max_num)` may return `1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop is pointless currently since it will always `break` on the first iteration.

Since you seem to want two random numbers, where `num_1 >= num_2`, a simple fix would be just:

```py
max_num = 1000
while True:
    num_1 = np.random.randint(1, max_num)
    num_2 = np.random.randint(1, max_num)

    if (num_1 >= num_2):
        break
```

This will keep looping, picking fresh pairs of random numbers, until the desired condition (`num_1 >= num_2`) is met.

Answer (score 4):

In your condition:

```
if (num_1 < num_2):
      num_2 = np.random.randint(1, num_1)
```

`num_1` can equal to `1`. In this case this `np.random.randint(1, num_1)` gives the error, as the low and the high integers are equal.